# Get Index of Item from class in a Collection

Tags: c#

I have this collection:

```
private static ReadOnlyCollection<ArtikelClass[]> s_ArtikelTab =
           new ReadOnlyCollection<ArtikelClass[]>(new ArtikelClass[][]
           {
/*  0 */    new ArtikelClass[] {null},
/*  1 */    new ArtikelClass[] {null},
/*  2 */    new ArtikelClass[] {null},
/*  3 */    new ArtikelClass[] {null},
.
.
.
/*109 */    new ArtikelClass[] { new ArtikelClass("String 1",  1, false),
                                 new ArtikelClass("String 2",  2, false),
                                 new ArtikelClass("String 3",  3, true),
                                 new ArtikelClass("String 4",  4, false) },
});
public static ReadOnlyCollection<ArtikelClass[]> ArtikelTab { get { return s_ArtikelTab; } }
```

The class ArtikelClass looks like this:

```
internal class ArtikelClass
    {
        private String _artikel;
        private UInt16 _length;
        private bool _available;

        public String Artikel { get { return _artikel; } }
        public UInt16 Length { get { return _length; } }
        public bool Available { get { return _available; } }

        public ArtikelClass(String artikelname, UInt16 fulllength, bool availability)
        {
            _artikel = artikelname;
            _length = fulllength;
            _available= availability;
        }
    }
```

(Artikel means product in german)
Now i want to get the index of the entry with "String 3" in ArtikelClass to display the string and the integer.
I tried to use IndexOf but the item I am trying to find is not directly inside of the Collection and ArtikelClass does not have this function. 
 
Thank you for your help in advance and sorry if the english is not that good.
Greetings from Bavaria in Germany
 
**Edit:**
The strings are unique there will be only one "String 3" in the whole collection.

Comment: Maybe something like: `var s = s_ArtikelTab.SelectMany(a => a).Where(ac => ac != null && ac.Artikel == "String 3");` -- How this ends, depends on whether you can have multiple matches, a single match per dimension, a single match overall, or the first one or... I.e., you didn't specify if `String 3` IS unique, MUST be unique, may be duplicated and, if it is, how to treat it. -- You should post what you've tried so far, it's easier to understand what you're working with and what you're after.

Comment: @Jimi The strings are unique there will be just a single match in the whole collection

Comment: Any further *specification* belongs to the body of the question. Elaborate that phrase. -- Note that the LINQ query is a nested loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int artikelListCounter= 0; artikelListCounter < s_ArtikelTab.Count; artikelListCounter++){//Loop which iterates over the Collection of Arrays
    for(int artikelCounter= 0; artikelCounter < s_ArtikelTab[artikelListCounter].Count; artikelCounter++){//Loop which iterates over the Array of ArtikelClass objects
        var artikel = s_ArtikelTab[artikelListCounter][artikelCounter]
        if (s_ArtikelTab[artikelListCounter][artikelCounter].Artikel == "String3"){
            //That is the index in which of the lists the element is: artikelListCounter
            //That is the index of the element in the list: artikelListCounter
            //That is the object with the informations: artikel
        }
    }
}
```

Greetings from Baden-Wurttemberg